# How to use Payara Micro with xsbt-web-plugin?

Tags: payara, xsbt-web-plugin, payara-micro

I'm trying to set up a service with Payara Micro (5.191) and xsbt-web-plugin (4.0.2).

build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / organization := "local.test"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

lazy val testService = project
  .enablePlugins(ContainerPlugin)
  .settings(
    javaOptions in Container ++= Seq("-Xdebug", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      microprofile,
      servlet
    ),
    containerLibs in Container := Seq(
      "fish.payara.extras" % "payara-micro" % "5.191"
    ),
    containerLaunchCmd in Container := { (port, path) =>
      Seq("fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro")
    }
  )

lazy val microprofile = {
    sys.props += "packaging.type" -> "jar"
    "org.eclipse.microprofile" % "microprofile" % "2.2" % "provided" pomOnly()
  }
lazy val servlet = "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "4.0.1" % "provided"
```

Main.scala:

```
package local.test

import java.util
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application
import local.test.endpoint.Hello

@ApplicationPath("/*")
class Main extends Application {

  override def getClasses: util.Set[Class[_]] = {
    val h = new util.HashSet[Class[_]]
    h.add(classOf[Hello])
    h
  }
}
```

Hello.scala:

```
package local.test.endpoint

import javax.ws.rs.core.{MediaType,Response}
import javax.ws.rs.{GET, Path, Produces, QueryParam}

@Path("/hello")
class Hello {

  @GET
  @Produces(Array(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
  def getMessage(@QueryParam("name") name: String): Response = {
    Response.ok("Hallo " + name).build
  }

  @GET
  @Produces(Array(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
  def getMessage: Response = {
    Response.ok("Hallo Nobody").build
  }
}
```

The server starts and shows no errors, but I can not open the web site.

1) Is http://localhost:8080/test the right URL?
2) How can I check if this application is deployed?
3) What did I miss?

Comment: How does Payara Micro know which classes to serve?  Is there a configuration file, JVM property, or similar needed to specify `local.test.Main` as an entry point?

Comment: As far as I know, it should be through the `javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath` interface of the `Main` class. With the `getClasses` function the endpoints were found.

Comment: How does it know that the `main` class is `local.test.Main`?  Does it scan the class path for all `main` classes, or is there a way to configure that?

Comment: I think the key is the `--deploy` argument.  With that, I was able to get Payara Micro to find and attempt to launch the service, but fail with what appears to be issues in the annotations.  Try changing your `containerLaunchCmd` to `Seq("fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro", "--deploy", "testService/target/webapp")` and see if you can reproduce.

Comment: I was able to get it working with two changes.  1. Add `--deploy` as described in the above comment.  2. Remove one of the `getMessage` methods from `Hello`

Comment: I got it working. I changed the `launcherCmd` to `Seq("fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro", "--deploy", "target/webapp", "--contextroot", "/")` and removed the second `getMessage` as suggested. I also need an `webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` with the root element only.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome.  You might want to write that up below as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from earldouglas (many thanks for that), I got it running:

Project files:

```
/project-root
  + project/
  |   + build.properties (single line content: sbt.version=1.2.8)
  |   + plugins.sbt (single line content: addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "4.0.2") )
  |
  + src/main/
  |   + scala/local/test/
  |   |   + endpoint/
  |   |   |   + Hello.scala
  |   |   + Main.scala
  |   + webapp/WEB-INF/
  |       + web.xml
  |
  + build.sbt
```

Hello.scala: like in the question above, but remove the second GET-request. Two equal requests on the same endpoint don't work.

Main.scala: see above

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

build.sbt: like above, but replace lines

```
containerLaunchCmd in Container := { (port, path) =>
  Seq("fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro")
}
```

with

```
containerLaunchCmd in Container := { (port, path) =>
  Seq("fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro", "--deploy", "target/webapp", "--contextroot", "/")
}
```

and also change the project val to

```
lazy val testService = (project in file("."))
```

maybe you want to change contextroot depending on your needs.

With every source change you need to run `container:start`.

After payara micro is started, you can check it:
`curl localhost:8080/hello`
`curl localhost:8080/application.wadl`

**UPDATE**
the files are available as example project at

https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/tree/master/docs/examples/payara-micro